# BIP Report in Siebel Open UI

Tags: siebel, bi-publisher

I created BIP report in Siebel Open UI. In my screen got two Applet :

- Information Applet - use Information BC
- Transaction Applet - use Transaction BC

In Information Applet got two drop down field which are Acc and Credit Note No (for drop down field i use calculated field). The link between this two Applet is Credit Note No. 
So i set my link

- Information BC - CreditNoteNo (Calculated Field)
- Transaction BC - Credit Note No (BC Field).

But when the reports come out, only the data from Information BC was come out and there's no data from Transaction BC was display.

Kindly assist me on this.

Answer (score 0):

In the My Reports view, where the generated reports are finally stored in Siebel, check the fields searchpec and bookmark, to see if the right searchspec was captured from the UI.

The UI applets have nothing to do with BIP except to capture the searchspec.

In Siebel Admininistration->BIP reports view for this report, try unchecking the selected records flag and try running the report again.

In Siebel Admininistration->BIP reports view, find the Integration Object of the report (left side applet under the top list applet). This integration object will be used to create the XML to generate the report. That integration object can be found in Siebel Tools, and it should have the same BCs as in the UI applets.  Check the BO behind that IO, if that link is present.

Comment: Hai Ranjith, i already check search spec and bookmark in my BIP Report. It capture right searchspec. The flag is already unchecked and the link in BO is there.